# How to Reset Mouse Tracking to Default settings

Tags: macos, mouse

I don't know what causes this to happen, but sometimes when I move my mouse left and right very quickly it causes *something* to happen to my mouse settings and my tracking speed gets cranked WAY up. The settings in the Control Panel don't actually change though so the slider that lets you control the mouse tracking speed is still in the spot I used to have it... but it is like some kind of multiplier has been added to my tracking. It happened again today and I've adjusted the Tracking speed all the way to its lowest setting, but my mouse is still tracking across the screen WAY too fast and it's making it hard for me to do detailed clicking.

I'm using a wired usb mouse (Razer Deathadder Elite). Mac Studio. Ventura 13.3.1.